# Decoded Images Some Times are Rotated by 90degree

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

hey every one I am Trying to Load Large Images to BackGround of my App Using This Code :

```
        final Drawable drawable =new BitmapDrawable(colorResource,decodeFile(new File(LMApplication.sharedpreferences.getString(path,""))));    

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            if(LMApplication.CurrentSDK < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                            }else{
                                view.setBackground(drawable);
                            }
                        }
                });


public Bitmap decodeFile(File input){
            Bitmap bmpCompressed = null;
            try {
                //Decode image size

                BitmapFactory.Options o11 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o11.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(input),null,o11);

                //The new size we want to scale to
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE=500;

                //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                int scale=1;
                while(o11.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o11.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale*=2;

                //Decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o22 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o22.inSampleSize=scale;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(input), null, o22);
                bmpCompressed = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(input.toString(), o22);

                //    FileOutputStream out = null;
                try {
             //      out = new FileOutputStream(file);
              //     bmpCompressed.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); 

                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                   try{
                 //      out.close();
                   } catch(Throwable ignore) {}
                }

               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
              return bmpCompressed;
              }
```

But Some Images are Rotated 90 degree to the left after the decoding, is there any Problem here or is there any way i can prevent this?

UPDATE :

Changed the Code like This and now prepared for every thing :

```
    public Bitmap decodeFile(File input){
            Bitmap bmpCompressed = null;
            try {
                //Decode image size

                BitmapFactory.Options o11 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o11.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(input),null,o11);

                //The new size we want to scale to
             //   final int REQUIRED_SIZE=500;

               int width = getDimensions.WIDTH;

               int height = getDimensions.HEIGHT;
                //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                int scale=1;
                while(o11.outWidth/scale/2>=width && o11.outHeight/scale/2>=height)
                    scale*=2;

                //Decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o22 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o22.inSampleSize=scale;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(input), null, o22);
                bmpCompressed = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(input.toString(), o22);


                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(input.getAbsolutePath());

               int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

               if(orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL){

                   int rotatesize;

                   switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotatesize = -90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotatesize = -180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotatesize = -270;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

               Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
               matrix.postRotate(90);
               bmpCompressed = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpCompressed, 0, 0, bmpCompressed.getWidth(), bmpCompressed.getHeight(), matrix, true);

               }
                //    FileOutputStream out = null;
                try {
             //      out = new FileOutputStream(file);
              //     bmpCompressed.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); 

                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                   try{
                 //      out.close();
                   } catch(Throwable ignore) {}
                }

               } catch (IOException e) {}
              return bmpCompressed;
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ExifInterface for rotate like this

```
picturePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(picturePath);
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
switch (orientation) {
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
    matrix.postRotate(180);
    break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
    matrix.postRotate(270);
    break;
default:
    break;
}

myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
bitmap.recycle();
```

Note : Here `picturePath` is selected Image's path from `Gallery`

Comment: yeah but problemis exifinterface creates 1 bitmap + bitmap from convertion , so OOM is throwed, any way ty

Comment: no its not for `ExifInterface`. It is used to rotate the `matrix`. Try to recycle all bitmaps after use like i show u in answer.

Comment: If OOM occurs then try to `inSample` those images.

Comment: ofcourse i did, but some images are just too damn big

Comment: have u try to scale those bitmaps

Comment: yep, i needed this image for background of my app, which is optional, so i made a method to scale it equal to phone's dimensions, because i didnt want its quality be reduced, only way to do so was using a library which could keep a bitmap in its cache and releasing memory but i couldnt figure out how the lib works, so i said "Let users big ass do it themselves " ;D

Comment: Hey I need to know How to rotate the raw data without converting it to bitmap. Please help

Comment: don't understand what do u mean @therealprashant

Comment: I will explain..in OnpictureTaken we get byte[] data as argument..and eventually we store this in the gallery..but how to rotate this byte[] data  if we want to save full size images in the gallery .(And I have to achieve this without converting it into bitmap) is there some method available

Comment: while taking picture from camera u have to rotate the bitmap before saving it in gallery @therealprashant

Comment: I am developing a test camera app and i am monitoring the heap memory through memory monitor tool in android studio . When I save the normal picture there is no bloat in memory but when I rotate it (by first converting it into bitmap) then there is a huge bloat in memory..I have to avoid this..so I think coversion into Bitmap is the culprit which I need to avoid so i need to rotate the array byte itself without converting it any idea ? lets have a proper chat elsewhere..please ping me prashantpandeyfun10@gmail.com ..It will be a great help...thankyou

Comment: I don't have idea u can ask anyone in chat on stackoverfolw [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/androidians) , [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era) @therealprashant there are may chat rooms

Comment: @NNE Thankyou for the help..I dint know there is chat room facility available here :)